# Sending USSD code with alphabetic characters

Tags: android, character-encoding, character, ussd

In my android app, I am sending `USSD` codes (`#144#73#`) using below `Intent` :

```
String baseUssd = Uri.encode("#") + "144" + Uri.encode("#");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(baseUssd);
builder.append("73");
builder.append(Uri.encode("#"));

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + builder.toString()));
```

It's working well.

What I want now is to send this code :

**`#144#73MA#`**

I run this using the dial pad, following the ***Operator USSD menu***, that worked.
But if I try to do this ***programmatically*** using the above `Intent` that didn't work.

I know that alphabetic characters can't be used when typing code with the Dial Pad, but I though that It can be possible programmatically !!

Any Idea please !

**Edit**

When I try to send this programmatically : **`#144#73MA#`** I noticed that the Dialer application changes the alphabetic characters to their corresponding **digit** in the dial pad. Meaning that the dialer transform this : **`#144#73MA#`**

to this `#144#73`**`62`**`#` : why ?

Because :

- the `M` matches the digit `6`
- the `A` matches the digit `2`

Comment: _using the above Intent that didn't work_ --- Please define how exactly it did not work.

Comment: Thanks @shoerat, Happy to see your comment ! Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Meaning that the dialer transform this : **`#144#73MA#`**
>
> to this `#144#73`**`62`**`#` : why ?

I will try to answer only the **why** part.

`Intent.ACTION_CALL` is handled by [`OutgoingCallBroadcaster`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/master/src/com/android/phone/OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java) class. If you look at `processIntent()` method, there is this piece of code (lines 438~448 as of this writing):

```
String number = PhoneNumberUtils.getNumberFromIntent(intent, this);
// Check the number, don't convert for sip uri
// TODO put uriNumber under PhoneNumberUtils
if (number != null) {
    if (!PhoneNumberUtils.isUriNumber(number)) {
        number = PhoneNumberUtils.convertKeypadLettersToDigits(number);
        number = PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(number);
    }
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "The number obtained from Intent is null.");
}
```

There [`PhoneNumberUtils.convertKeypadLettersToDigits()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#convertKeypadLettersToDigits%28java.lang.String%29) converts the letters into the equivalent numeric digits:

> public static String **convertKeypadLettersToDigits** (String input)
>
> Translates any alphabetic letters (i.e. [A-Za-z]) in the specified phone number into the equivalent numeric digits, according to the phone keypad letter mapping described in ITU E.161 and ISO/IEC 9995-8.
>
> **Returns**
>   the input string, with alpha letters converted to numeric digits using the phone keypad letter mapping. For example, an input of "1-800-GOOG-411" will return "1-800-4664-411".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful ! But just tell me please, is it possible to  change this behaviour ? by overriding the `OutgoingCallBroadcaster` method or something like that ?!

Comment: I don't see how that could be achieved unless if you can use other special characters instead of alphabetic letters; e.g., `~&` instead of `MA`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I am making an app to use USSD codes of operators. I can't change the codes !