# Call intent with decimal points in an USSD code

Tags: android, android-intent, ussd

In my android app, I want to dial an ussd code something like -- *123*1*0.5# -- the code I'm using is like this

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode( "*123*1*"+"0.5"+"#")));

And I know that's working because I log it, and I got the right expression, but when the dialer of the phone opens, it erases the dot and shows me this.
*123*1*05#  - YOU CAN SEE THE DOT IS MISSING.

The first it's not an encoding problem, in fact the dot is one of the unreserved characters that UTF-8 leaves untouched.

A probable solution to this problem might be answer #2 of this post... [How to send a USSD code containing decimal floating point (.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196006/how-to-send-a-ussd-code-containing-decimal-floating-point) which is overwrite the intent for NEW_OUTGOING_CALL but I tried and didn't work. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Remember the problem is not about the encoding, is about changing the number that the dial Intent is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Dot is not a valid character in a tel: scheme intent. It's usually used to separate groups of digits in a phonenumber and I *suspect* it's stripped out by the dialer before sending as dtmf, even if it's an allowed alphanumeric character for USSD.

Comment: Well the Android Studio help says it's. And besides it's all inside de encode, aIso I tried to encode just de dot, and the bad result remains. As you suspect the dialer is who eat the dot, cause the app send it in the Intent.