# Android code to dial or calll a string containing alphabets *123*abc# instead of numbers (*123#)?

Tags: java, android

I’m unable to dial or call a string containing alphabets in android.

For Example:
I want to dial a string *123*abcd#.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*123*abcd#")); //This string is not getting dialed 
                try
                {

                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
                catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

String *123*abcd# is not getting dialed or called. Please help to solve the same.

Comment: Have you added this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: Hi Ahamed,  Yes,I've added the permission to manifest file.

Comment: Yes i ve added the same. This doesnt solve my question

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "*123*abcd#";
if ((s.startsWith("*")) && (s.endsWith("#"))) {
    callstring = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
    callstring = callstring + Uri.encode("#");
} 
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + callstring));
startActivity(i);
```

your need to encode the # before using it above code will do the trick.

Comment: @DäñishShärmà glad it helped. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: i didn't ask the question. I was trying to find the solution for #Gurpreet.

Comment: @DäñishShärmà sorry my mistake

Comment: you are from ludhiana. Java companies exists there ?. I'm working in mohali, even here no more opportunities for java

Comment: @DäñishShärmà there are one or two companies in ludhiana which deals in java. :) not much

Comment: I know, I've to encode #.  The snippet you posted will dial only (*123*#) as abcd is getting lost.

Comment: Hi sahil,I know i ve to encode #. The snippet posted by you will dial only *123*# as "abcd" is omitted.                                                                             But i want to dial entire string (*123*abcd#).

Comment: @Gurpreet. let me search a bit

Comment: @Gurpreet read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22935687/2299040 your character are converting to numeric representation. the above link has a good explanantion

Comment: @Sahil: I went through the same. Is there any way out for the chars not to get convert into numeric values when received on handset from app.

Answer (score 0):

To use Intent.ACTION_CALL you need to add Permission 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` and since its a Dangerous permission you need to handle it Runtime for Android 6 and above.

You can rather use Intent.ACTION_DIAL which doesnt require any permission and will open the Phone app with the given number typed already, the user has to initiate the call.

Here is how to achieve this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123*abcd#"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This doesnt  solve the purpose, as it will dial only *123* as abcd and # will get omitted. is there  any way to get abcd dialed in handset from app